# Can someone please explain ask and ask-concurrent in layman's term?

Tags: netlogo

I'm really having a hard time grasping this concept. When I use it, it doesn't really seem like it's performing it **at the same time**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't yet, I recommend trying the Ask Concurrent Code Example in the Code Example section of the Models Library.  Run it at a slow speed.

As I understand it, `ask-concurrent` isn't really supposed to run procedures in the turtles simultaneously.  The claim in the Programming Guide is that `ask-concurrent` runs each single command in `ask [...]` sequentially, one turtle at a time.  It differs from `ask` in that if there are *multiple* commands within the braces, `ask-concurrent` will run the first command in one turtle, then run the same command in another turtle, and so on, until it has run that first command in each of the turtles `ask`ed.  Then it runs the second command in the first turtle chosen, then in the second, and so on.  By contrast, `ask` will run all of the commands within the braces for the first turtle.  Then it will run all of the commands for the second turtle, and so on.

So the difference between `ask` and `ask-concurrent` only shows up if there is more than one command in the braces, and even then, `ask-concurrent` still deals with turtles in sequence.

Comment: Also, from the [Programming Guide](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask-concurrent): The `forward` (`fd`) and `back` (`bk`) commands are treated specially. When used inside `ask-concurrent`, these commands can take multiple turns to execute. During its turn, the turtle can only move by one step. Thus, for example, `fd 20` is equivalent to `repeat 20 [ fd 1 ]`, where the turtle's turn ends after each run of `fd`. If the distance specified isn't an integer, the last fraction of step takes a full turn. So for example `fd 20.3` is equivalent to `repeat 20 [ fd 1 ] fd 0.3.`

Comment: `ask-concurrent` exists only for backwards compatibility with very old versions of NetLogo. I would not recommend using it at all, for anything.